# Symfony2 Doctrine ManyToMany doesn't persist

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, relation

Hey guys I'm looking for help again.

My problem is that two related ORM entities not getting stored.

I run the following Unit test and it fails:

```
public function testCategoryRelation()
{
    $doctrine = $this->client->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
    $itemRepo = $doctrine->getRepository("AppBundle:Item");
    $item = $itemRepo->find(230045);
    $this->assertTrue($item instanceof \Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Item);

    $categories = $item->getCategories();
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $categories->count());
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $this->assertTrue($category instanceof \Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Category);
    }

    $count = $categories->count();
    $categoryRepo = $doctrine->getRepository("AppBundle:Category");
    $categories = $categoryRepo->findBy(array(), null, 2);
    $this->assertEquals( 2, count($categories) );

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $this->assertTrue($category instanceof \Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Category);
        $category->addItem($item);
        $item->addCategory($category);
    }
    $this->assertGreaterThan($count, $item->getCategories()->count());

    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $em->persist($category);
    }
    $em->persist($item);
    $em->flush();
    $em->clear($item);

    $item = $itemRepo->find(230045);
    $categories = $item->getRelatedItems();
    $this->assertGreaterThan($count, $categories->count()); /* Here it fails */
}
```

I have no clue why the last test fails. Could you please help me find my mistake?

I run Symfony 2.1.4 together with Doctrine 2.3

I have two ORM Objects.

### 1. Item

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="item")
 */
class Item
{

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="items")
   */
  private $categories;

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
  }

  /**
   * @param \Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Category $category
   */
  public function addCategory(\Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Category $category)
  {
      $this->categories[] = $category;
      return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
   */
  public function getCategories()
  {
      return $this->categories;
  }
}
```

### 2. Category

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\TestBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
  /**
   * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="categories")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="category_item",
   *   joinColumns={
   *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   *   },
   *   inverseJoinColumns={
   *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   *   }
   * )
   */
  private $items;

  /**
   * @param \Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Item $item
   * @return Category
   */
  public function addItem(\Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Item $item)
  {
      $this->items[] = $item;
      return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
   */
  public function getItems()
  {
      return $this->items;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: ... and what does the error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, `$categories = $item->getRelatedItems();`. Maybe it is better to write `$categories = $item->getCategories();`?

The other suggestion is to add __construct method to Category entity class and initialize $items with `new ArrayCollection`